# How to determine frequency of codeword at each position in a string

Tags: r

I have several strings, of variable length, examples below:

```
sequences <- c("ABCDEFGH", "FGHABCDEF")
```

I also have a "key" which is a clustered version of overlapping sub-strings of these sequences above.

```
key <- data.frame(codewords = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
       substrings = c("BCD, FGH", "CDE, EFG", "ABC, DEF", "GHA, HAB"))
```

I want to look at the frequency of these `codewords` starting at each position of each of the sequences.

So for example, I see that codeword 3 starts at position 1 of the string once (ABC), codeword 1 starts at position 2 of the string once, etc...

I want to look at the frequency of the position at which each of the codewords start at for all of the sequences.

For this example, I am looking for an output like the following:

```
StartingPosition     Codeword    Occurences
1     1     1
1     2     0
1     3     1
1     4     0
2     1     1
2     2     0
2     3     0
2     4     1
3     1     0
3     2     1
3     3     0
3     4     1
4     1     0
4     2     0
4     3     2
4     4     0
```

However, my actual data has 100 codewords and over 10000 sequences. I am looking for a computationally efficient way of doing this. The max number of starting positions is always going to be the longest sequence (in this case 9 letters) minus 3 + 1 = 7 in this case, as all of the codewords are of length 3. Codeword length is variable for my use also, so I would like a way to be able to do this regardless of codeword length.

Please feel free to ask for clarification if needed!

Thanks

Comment: How is the second part of the substrings relevant?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Just added. I hope that helps. Thank you :)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Both of those triplet strings correspond to one codeword. So if BCD or FGH show up, I treat them as the same (codeword 1).

Comment: Codeword 3 corresponds to the substrings "ABC, DEF". ABC starts at position 1 in "ABCDEFGH".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
key$substrings <- sub(",\\s", "|", key$substrings)
res <- lapply(key$substrings, function(x) {
  x <- gregexpr(x, text = sequences)
  setNames(as.data.frame(table(unlist(x))), c("StartingPosition", "Occurences"))
})

res <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, res, 
                          codeword = key$codewords, 
                          substrings = key$substrings))
res <- subset(res, StartingPosition != -1)

#   StartingPosition Occurences codeword substrings
#1                 1          1        1    BCD|FGH
#2                 2          1        1    BCD|FGH
#3                 5          1        1    BCD|FGH
#4                 6          1        1    BCD|FGH
#5                 3          1        2    CDE|EFG
#6                 6          1        2    CDE|EFG
#7                 1          1        3    ABC|DEF
#8                 4          2        3    ABC|DEF
#9                 7          1        3    ABC|DEF
#11                2          1        4    GHA|HAB
```

You can easily fill in the 0 occurences afterwards.

The steps are essentially:

- Turn the `key$substrings` into usable pattern for regular expressions using the logical OR instead of comma separation
- Using `gregexpr` determine the starting positions of each substring pattern in each sequence
- Extract all the starting positions and count occurences per substring/codeword
- Add the codeword numbers and substrings to the resulting data.frame
- Remove entries where Startingposition is -1 because this indicates that no match was found for a given codeword

---

If we have multiple occurences of a codeword in a string, this will give you all the starting positions. For example:

```
sequences <- "ABCDEFABC"

res <- lapply(key$substrings, function(x) {
  x <- gregexpr(x, text = sequences)
  setNames(as.data.frame(table(unlist(x))), c("StartingPosition", "Occurences"))
})

res <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, res, 
                          codeword = key$codewords, 
                          substrings = key$substrings))
res <- subset(res, StartingPosition != -1)

#  StartingPosition Occurences codeword substrings
#1                2          1        1    BCD|FGH
#2                3          1        2    CDE|EFG
#3                1          1        3    ABC|DEF    # 1. occurence of ABC
#4                4          1        3    ABC|DEF    
#5                7          1        3    ABC|DEF    # 2. occurence of ABC
```

Comment: I know I didn't include this in my question, but what if I had a sequence which had the same triplet twice? For example, "ABCDEFABC"?

Comment: @KeshavM, see my updated answer for your question in comment and also the slightly changed order which is important.

Comment: @KeshavM if you don’t want multiple matches reported you can use regexpr instead of gregexpr.